# DeletionPolicy retain causing problems

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, yaml, aws-cloudformation

i am trying to import an existing ddb table into my cf yaml with the following code:

```
UserPreferencesDDBTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: subid
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: subid
        KeyType: RANGE
    SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
    TableName: 'test-user-preferences'
```

in the cloud formation stack events i see  that it's trying to create it and fails because resource with this name exists.
what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: How exactly are you importing it?

Comment: i need to do something in addition?.

Comment: I mean, are you following [the steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) to import a resource?

Comment: yes, i tried it. not working. this ddb instance created manually long time ago

Comment: Can you be more specific why it didn't work? Any errors? In general importing of DdB works, I did it myself.

Comment: i have tried to updated my stack with that those yaml lines added to my old template without editing any other resource. i dont know why the stack is trying to create this resource although it exists.  `CREATE_FAILED   test-user-preferences already exists`. this is the error from the stack events

Comment: Are you sure you are using "Create stack with existing resources" option?

Comment: i am not doing it from the gui nor from the cli, its part of CI/CD job. all the other resources are exactly the same as been before, no change made.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it from CI/CD. I'm not aware of such functionality in CodePipeline.